# Changing an item in 2 dimensional array class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I've managed getting an item by command with the help of this page. It works but it seems complicated.

```
cout << arr[x][y];
```

Now, how can I change a specific number in the array by typing something like:

```
arr[4][5]=10;
```

My code example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array {
private:
    int row, col;
    int** arr;
    int size;
    int count = 0;
public:
    Array() { arr = 0; size = 0; }
    Array(int row, int col);

    // a piece of code from stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload
    class Proxy {
    private:
        int* _arr;
    public:
        Proxy(int* _arr)  { 
            this->_arr = _arr; 
        }
        int operator[](int index) {
            return _arr[index];
        }
    };

    Proxy operator[](int index) {
        return Proxy(arr[index]);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
};

Array::Array(int row, int col) {
    size = row*col;
    this->row = row;
    this->col = col;
    arr = new int* [row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[col];
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    Array first(5,5);
    cout << first[0][0] << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: One star programming, 2 star programming, I wonder where this should lead to.

Comment: Seriously, can you help?

Comment: Sure I can: [Don't use raw pointers in c++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: I also sell good [SEP field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_else%27s_problem) generators, if you need to apply one to your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally did it by simply putting an &. It was silly

...

```
    int& operator[](int index) {
        return _arr[index];
    }
```

...